# Angular change color on table row

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJs table

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in blankettInfoData">
   <td>{{data.informationstyp}}</td>
   <td>{{data.rubricering}}</td>
   <td>{{data.dokumenttyp}}</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.checked"/></td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to change the color of one row when this happens:

1. When I add a new row to the list (Green color). Code should be something like this: "If (data.informationstyp == 'ABC123') then change color to green"
2. When I check the checkbox (Red color). Code should be something like this: if (checkbox is checked) then change color to red".

Please help me

Comment: What about when both the cases are true?

Comment: @Vivz Yes, you are right. I have to think about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular directive `ng-class` for this

**HTML**:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in blankettInfoData" ng-class="{'green': data.informationstyp == 'ABC123', 'red': data.checked == true}">
   <td>{{data.informationstyp}}</td>
   <td>{{data.rubricering}}</td>
   <td>{{data.dokumenttyp}}</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.checked"/></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**:

```
.red{
color:red;
}
.green{
color:green;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your  blankettInfoData array?Are you getting any error in console?